# How do I use D3.nest ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3.nest unsuccessfully. I just want to build a simple table like this http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/. As I'm following this example everything work fine but when I'm adding this code

```
var people = d3.nest() 
            .key(function(d) { return d.authorname;}) 
            .rollup(function(d) {
                    return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.linkclicks;}); 
        }).entries(people);
         console.log(people);
```

My data doesn't show up anymore in the table. I've only the title of the column. However Looking at the console my data are well grouped. Here is my entire code :

```
        <script>
       function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

    return table;
}


// create some people

var url = 'http://localhost:5000/authors';

function doData(error, people){
         if (error) throw error;

    var people = d3.nest() 
        .key(function(d) { return d.authorname;}) 
        .rollup(function(d) {
                return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.linkclicks;}); 
    }).entries(people);
     console.log(people);



    // render the table
    var peopleTable = tabulate(people, ["authorname", "linkclicks"]);

    // uppercase the column headers
    peopleTable.selectAll("thead th")
        .text(function(column) {
            return column.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + column.substr(1);
        });

    // sort by age
    peopleTable.selectAll("tbody tr")
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.descending(a.linkclicks, b.linkclicks);
        });  
 };  

d3.json(url, doData); 
console.log("Hello World!");

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not appending any elements. If the elements are there, your selectors should be `.selectAll("thead > th")` maybe?

Comment: no, no, I just didn't wanted to put the all code. actually my table is showing up with my data and all. It's just the D3.nest stuff that doesn't work

Comment: What does your data look like? What's happening instead of what you expect to happen?

Comment: In its current form this question is *impossible* to answer.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I'll see how I can improve my question.

Comment: The nested data has a different structure. You can't use the same function you use for the unnested data without modifications.